# Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, homestead, console.log

In OS X with Laravel/Homestead, I'm getting an error using Vue (v2.2.1).  The component won't load and the console error is "Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function".

*Full console error*

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:321), <anonymous>:17:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:321)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
        at app.js:64
        at app.js:67
```

What is throwing me off is that if I make a change to app.js, the webpack does not update to reflect any changes.  So I need to A) fix the issue above, and B) figure out how to get the webpack to show updates in the console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm a noob.  Here is my code...

*app.js file*

```
    Vue.component('video-upload', require('./components/VideoUpload.vue'));

    const app = new Vue({
        el: 'body'
    });
```

*VideoUpload.vue*

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Example</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            This is an example
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
        }
    </script>
```

*upload.blade.php*

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <video-upload></video-upload>
    @endsection
```

*package.json*

```
    {
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "prod": "gulp --production",
        "dev": "gulp watch"
      },
        "devDependencies": {
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.0",
        "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
        "laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
        "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
        "lodash": "^4.14.0",
        "video.js": "^5.11.6",
        "vue": "^2.2.1",
        "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
      }
    }
```

Comment: nothing's wrong with your code. so, i think laravel elixir webpack official that gives you problem here https://github.com/vuejs/laravel-elixir-vue-2/issues/20 . laravel mix is a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1

Change your *package.json*

```
"laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0"
```

And run

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
npm install
```

**OR**

## 2

```
npm install laravel-elixir-vue-2 --save-dev
```

## And then

Change your gulpfile.js like this

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Once updated to Vue 2, the next console error was "[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead."   I simply wrapped the component in a <div>, re-ran Gulp, and everything works beautifully.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 59):

After an update from `laravel-mix 5.0.9` to `laravel-mix 6.0.11` on a laravel 7 project it started to see this error on vue compiled views. I change the call the Vue package:

> Use `import Vue from 'vue'` instead of `window.Vue = require("vue");` worked for me.

Comment: Sure fixed my issue, it was `Vue.use is not a function`.

Comment: Solved my issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also solved by Vue.use.component is not a function

You will also need to change all your `Vue.default.XXXX` by `Vue.XXXX`

Comment: I'm using more or less the same configuration and this worked for me too in Laravel 8 and Vue 2.6. Thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, but does anyone understand why this problem occurs when updating to `laravel-mix 6.0.x`?

Answer (score 18):

import vue properly in your code using import keyword like this:

```
//import vue
import Vue from 'vue';

//register component
Vue.component('yourComponentName',require('./components/yourComponentName.vue').default);

//initialize vue
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: I wasn't using Elixer, so this worked for me, thnx!

Answer (score 15):

For any one who has the same issue and is not related to Laravel.

**Hint: using Vue 3+**

Register the component globally:

```
const MyComponent = {
  // ... options ...
}

// if you do not have App component
Vue.createApp({}).component("my-component", MyComponent).mount("#app");

// if you have an App component
const App = {
  // ... options ...
}
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.component("my-component", MyComponent);
app.mount("#app");
```

Please refer to [Documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#component-names) for more info

Answer (score 4):

CHECK YOUR CDN VUE VERSION. THEY CHANGED FROM VUE 2 TO VUE 3.

This scenarion happened here, we were using Vue 2 and our CDN changed the global script to Vue 3.

Vue 3 changed the "Vue.component" to "Vue.directive" which broke our application.

Answer (score 4):

VUE.JS CDN changed the global script to Vue 3 which is not supported [Vue.component] any more.

Use Vue Version 2.6.14, this works for me (older apps)
[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});


<body>
 <div id="app">.....</div>`
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```
/*import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'*/ before
/*require('./bootstrap');*/
  
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./component/mainapp.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
});
```